# rich text field and visualforce table

Tags: visualforce, html

I am quite new in visualforce. I am generating a PDF from a visualforce page but the issue is that when I try to insert a rich text field(called Quote.Hardware_configuration__c) in a table and then I see a double box for that field like in the screenshot below:[image]

CoulD you help me to fix this? Also I tried with outputtext but I could not achive my goal.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" action="{!populatePriceOnQuote}" extensions="QuotePDFController" showHeader="false"  applyHtmlTag="false"  renderAs="pdf">


    <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">

    @page { 
        size: letter portrait;
        <!--margin: 10%;-->
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 2cm;
        margin-top: 4cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
        font-family: 'SansSerif';
        @top-left {
            content: element(header_left);
        }

        @top-center {
            content: element(header_center);
        }

        @top-right {
            content: element(header_right);
        }

        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footer_left);
        }

        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer_center);
        }

        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page) " ("  counter(pages) ")";
        }
    }


.header_left {
    position: running(header_left);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color: #A0A0A0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';

}



.header_center{
    position: running(header_center);
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.header_right {
    text-align: right;
    position: running(header_right);
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayHeader1 {
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayHeader2 {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayBody {
    font-size: 10pt;
    page-break-after: always;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayBody2 {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

#quotePricing {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

#quotePricing td, #quotePricing th {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #4F81BD;
    p
    ing: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}

#quotePricing th {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #4F81BD;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#quotePricing tr.alt td {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #DBE5F1;
}


.footer_left {
    text-align: left;
    position: running(footer_left);
}

.footer_center {
    text-align: center;
    position: running(footer_center);
}

.footer_right {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
    position: running(footer_right);
}

.pageNumber:before {
    content: counter(page); 
}

.pageCount:before {
    content: counter(pages);  
}

.rayTD1 {

    color: #005380;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;

}




.rayTerms {

    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.rayTable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rayTable td {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0.5px solid #4F81BD;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}




</style>
</head>

<body>







<!-- start header -->

<div class="header_left"> {!Quote.Opportunity.Account.Name} {!YEAR(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!DAY(TODAY())}<br></br><br></br>Quote number: {!Quote.QuoteNumber} {!DAY(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!YEAR(TODAY())}</div>
<div class="header_right"><img src="{!$Resource.Logo}"></img></div>

<!-- End header -->


<br/>
<br/>
<div class="rayHeader2">HARDWARE</div>
<br/>
 <table id="quotePricing">
   <thead>
       <th width="12%">Quantity</th>
       <th>Product</th>
       <th width="20%">Comment</th>

   </thead>
<apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="line">
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}">
   <tr class="alt">
    <td width="12%"><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0}" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}"><apex:param value="{!line.Quantity}" /></apex:outputText></td>
     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.Prod_Name__c}" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}"></apex:OutputField></td>                            
     <td width="20%"><apex:OutputField value="{!Quote.Hardware_Configuration__c}" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}"></apex:OutputField></td>
  </tr>

  </apex:variable>
</apex:repeat>
</table><br/>


</body>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use <apex:outputText> instead of <apex:OutputField>  ?

Comment: Yes I tried that one but then the all table was hidden. "<apex:outputText escape="false" Value="{!Quote.Hardware_configuration__c}" />" I also tried escape=false but it did not work :( Anyother ideas? Thanks yuo

Comment: Would you show us the rest of your code please? If you're using any CSS 3, that could be the cause of your problem. There's clearly more to your code than just the table as I see no formatting or CSS for it. The PDF render engine only supports CSS 2.1 which could be the source of your issue.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev, I have updated the post with the rest of the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `applyHtmlTag="false"`? I've not seen that one before & don't know why you'd need it. Also, this should not be in your header: `<style type="text/css" media="print">`. You can add an @media statement to your CSS for `print`, but you don't want this in your header if you want to view it on screen.

Comment: Finally I have been able to do it. When I remove media="print" and using this line <apex:outputText escape="false" Value=" !Quote.Hardware_configuration__c}" /> then worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <apex:page standardController="Quote" action="{!populatePriceOnQuote}" extensions="QuotePDFController" showHeader="false"  applyHtmlTag="false"  renderAs="pdf">


    <head>
    <style type="text/css" >

    @page { 
        size: letter portrait;
        <!--margin: 10%;-->
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 2cm;
        margin-top: 4cm;
        margin-bottom: 2cm;
        font-family: 'SansSerif';
        @top-left {
            content: element(header_left);
        }

        @top-center {
            content: element(header_center);
        }

        @top-right {
            content: element(header_right);
        }

        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footer_left);
        }

        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer_center);
        }

        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page) " ("  counter(pages) ")";
        }
    }


.header_left {
    position: running(header_left);
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color: #A0A0A0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';

}



.header_center{
    position: running(header_center);
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.header_right {
    text-align: right;
    position: running(header_right);
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayHeader1 {
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayHeader2 {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayBody {
    font-size: 10pt;
    page-break-after: always;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

.rayBody2 {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
}

#quotePricing {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

#quotePricing td, #quotePricing th {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #4F81BD;
    p
    ing: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}

#quotePricing th {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #4F81BD;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#quotePricing tr.alt td {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #DBE5F1;
}


.footer_left {
    text-align: left;
    position: running(footer_left);
}

.footer_center {
    text-align: center;
    position: running(footer_center);
}

.footer_right {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'SansSerif';
    position: running(footer_right);
}

.pageNumber:before {
    content: counter(page); 
}

.pageCount:before {
    content: counter(pages);  
}

.rayTD1 {

    color: #005380;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;

}




.rayTerms {

    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.rayTable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rayTable td {
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0.5px solid #4F81BD;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}




</style>
</head>

<body>







<!-- start header -->

<div class="header_left"> {!Quote.Opportunity.Account.Name} {!YEAR(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!DAY(TODAY())}<br></br><br></br>Quote number: {!Quote.QuoteNumber} {!DAY(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!YEAR(TODAY())}</div>
<div class="header_right"><img src="{!$Resource.Logo}"></img></div>

<!-- End header -->


<br/>
<br/>
<div class="rayHeader2">HARDWARE</div>
<br/>
 <table id="quotePricing">
   <thead>
       <th width="12%">Quantity</th>
       <th>Product</th>
       <th width="20%">Comment</th>

   </thead>
<apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="line">
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}">
   <tr class="alt">
    <td width="12%"><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0}" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}"><apex:param value="{!line.Quantity}" /></apex:outputText></td>
     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.Prod_Name__c}" rendered="{!line.Product2.Product_Type__c ='Hardware'}"></apex:OutputField></td>                            
     <td width="20%"><apex:outputText escape="false" Value="{!Quote.Hardware_configuration__c}" /></td>
  </tr>

  </apex:variable>
</apex:repeat>
</table><br/>


</body>
</apex:page>
```