# How to display a list of text which contains bold information coming from apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce

In our scenario, I need to display a list of text in our Visualforce page. Some part of the text needs to be bold. I will explain this with the below simple but not working example:

**page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TestListOutputController">
    <apex:repeat var="ot" value="{!outText}" >
        <div>
            {!ot}
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**controller:**

```
public class TestListOutputController 
{
    public List<String> outText {get; set;}
    public TestListOutputController()
    {
        outText = new List<String>();
        outText.add('Hello <Strong>World</Strong>');
        outText.add('Sample <Strong>Text</Strong>');
    }
}
```

Obviously the strong tag here doesn't work. I can walk around this if the number of bold blocks is fixed. However, what if it is something like a blog section, or a stackexchange answer section? How should I handle such situations?

Comment: Use outputtext with escape false. If this will be a managed package you will have to explain during security review

Comment: related: [rich text field and visualforce table](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97836/rich-text-field-and-visualforce-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable markup, use an `<apex:outputText>` with the `escape` attribute set to false.

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="Hello <strong>world</strong>!" />
```

Be aware, though, that if you are trying to use this attribute in a managed package, it will likely cause you to fail security review.

Comment: How about using `RichText` directly.?

Comment: @RohitMourya Not sure what you're getting at in relation to `<apex:outputText>`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Visualforce component `<apex:outputText>` and set the `escape` attribute to `false`.

```
<apex:page controller="TestListOutputController">
    <apex:repeat var="ot" value="{!outText}" >
        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!ot}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Both answers are just equally awesome and I have to use order by who answers first to get the accepted answer. Thanks for your input though. It is really helpful.

Comment: Sounds fair to me. I'm glad I could help.